# How to assess the difference between columns?

Tags: r, bioinformatics

I have a data frame of enrichment scores for each sample with each gene signature. This is a study about a cancer drug.
It has too many variables, this is a small chunk of it:

```
                      EA595454     EA595455     EA595473     EA595500     EA595522     EA595529     EA595564
aDC                 2.724126e-01 6.876156e-02 1.141524e-01 1.836970e-01 7.171346e-02 1.100775e-01 1.184968e-01
Adipocytes          0.000000e+00 1.753762e-02 3.960170e-02 0.000000e+00 7.785961e-03 0.000000e+00 3.834048e-02
Astrocytes          0.000000e+00 1.207753e-02 1.771857e-02 3.130778e-18 3.241987e-18 4.683980e-18 1.019348e-02
B-cells             4.152846e-01 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 9.731611e-20 0.000000e+00 2.896445e-02 0.000000e+00
Basophils           9.119673e-02 1.663744e-02 5.863050e-18 1.537406e-02 3.616982e-17 1.354611e-02 8.168102e-21
CD4+ memory T-cells 1.215067e-01 4.698939e-03 5.579107e-21 6.997062e-03 7.624308e-03 5.387246e-03 1.605816e-02
CD4+ naive T-cells  2.257278e-02 2.410337e-18 1.039455e-18 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 1.151836e-17
CD4+ T-cells        3.305283e-18 0.000000e+00 1.464419e-17 0.000000e+00 3.670250e-17 3.764654e-18 1.086045e-18
CD4+ Tcm            0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 2.290124e-02 1.301887e-17 1.158197e-17 0.000000e+00
CD4+ Tem            0.000000e+00 1.379859e-18 5.538651e-18 5.677953e-19 1.241643e-17 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00
CD8+ naive T-cells  1.666841e-02 4.887379e-03 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 9.423647e-03 4.842848e-03 1.200533e-02
CD8+ T-cells        1.965776e-01 4.084210e-20 2.455955e-18 1.793326e-02 0.000000e+00 3.353038e-18 2.443909e-18
                        EA595565     EA595585    EA595597     EA595620     EA595621
aDC                 7.245196e-02 3.398515e-02 0.250885929 6.875483e-02 9.585878e-02
Adipocytes          5.145302e-02 1.184690e-18 0.010431807 2.591620e-02 8.936161e-03
Astrocytes          4.984505e-02 1.408421e-17 0.094669913 1.800831e-17 1.287466e-01
B-cells             5.296334e-02 3.264527e-18 0.064097117 0.000000e+00 1.691270e-18
Basophils           0.000000e+00 1.434844e-17 0.002107318 2.557110e-02 1.188495e-01
CD4+ memory T-cells 3.312491e-02 6.892757e-03 0.129432331 4.453861e-02 7.677784e-03
CD4+ naive T-cells  3.795570e-19 2.056169e-19 0.020466087 2.712376e-18 0.000000e+00
CD4+ T-cells        5.818215e-03 1.393160e-18 0.000000000 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00
CD4+ Tcm            3.783465e-02 0.000000e+00 0.000000000 8.206581e-18 0.000000e+00
CD4+ Tem            5.617115e-02 2.801627e-18 0.035137712 1.183050e-17 1.957861e-18
CD8+ naive T-cells  0.000000e+00 2.008825e-02 0.029528540 0.000000e+00 7.745590e-03
CD8+ T-cells        7.142028e-03 7.654567e-18 0.211596246 8.519580e-19 0.000000e+00
```

columns are samples, rows are gene signatures.. and the scores.

I organized the samples for responders vs non-responders.

My final goal is to build a volcano plot which visualizes the difference between the responders and non-responders, but first I need to run some analysis to asses this defference statistically.
How can I do that ?
Responder samples are from 1:89, non responders are 210:311.

does wilcoxon test do the job ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that a volcano plot is the best way to proceed with only 12 predictors per case.

Your model seems to be simply responders versus non-responders as an outcome variable, with the gene-signature scores as predictors. That suggests a logistic regression model that incorporates all of the gene-signature scores into a single model.

Volcano plots are often useful when you have hundreds to thousands of multiple individual genes tested for association with an outcome and want to see which genes are most likely to be reliably associated individually with outcome. But now all those individual gene expression values have been reduced to 12 gene-signature scores. A volcano plot on these values would thus only have 12 points. Furthermore, each of the signatures would be evaluated separately. It's quite possible that outcomes are associated with some combination of gene signatures, which the separate tests in a volcano plot would miss. The regression coefficients for the individual gene signatures would indicate which ones are most associated with outcome.

By the way, as a practical matter you might want to pre-process the data to set the numerical values that are very close to 0 to 0 exactly. It looks like all your values below `1e-03` are effectively 0.